# Swift 3 CommandLine.arguments fails

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta6

In a playground, when I write:
`let arguments = CommandLine.arguments`

I get an error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

The other CommandLine type properties, `CommandLine.arg` and `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` work fine, so I think I am seeing an error. Wanted to ask here before I post a Radar.

I'm using Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) which I believe is the GM, not the final release.

Comment: It's just that Playground don't support input arguments, CommandLine doesn't work in Playgrounds. The error message could be better, that's for sure.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks Eric Aya